# How to avoid re-authentication when signing-in with Facebook through Firebase in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a log in with Facebook functionality in my Ionic app using Firebase. The first log in on device works fine, but then if I log out and then trying to log in back it takes about 1 minute. I believe that happens because the user is re-authenticated. This is my function:

```
 facebookLogin(){
this.facebook.login(["email"]).then((loginResponse) => {
  let credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken);
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((info) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(info));
  });
});
```

}

I found something about avoiding un-needed re-authentication here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login , at "Advanced: Handle the sign-in flow manually". I don't figure out how could I implement that in my function to do not re-auth the user every time.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean it takes one minute? Why would that be related to -reauthentication?

Comment: When I press the login button, the loading animation runs for about one minute before successfully signing-in. I do not know if that is related to re-auth, but that's the only possible solution that came up in my mind. The weird fact is that the facebook sign-in is behaving the same with Ionic auth, too.

Comment: Can you isolate which call is pending for a minute? Is it the `this.facebook.login` call or `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential`, etc.

Comment: I changed my function to look like this: facebookSignIn(){
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((user) => {
      console.log("Successful facebook sign-in!");
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
  }  It works very smootly now.

Comment: Cool, glad it works now.